# What can I do to a chain link fence to make it dog proof?

Tags: fence, pet-proofing

I have a chain link fence which is pretty high but my neighbors' pit bull constantly climbs the fence to get over to my yard.  I am scared of this dog and the Law Dog has been called numerous times about this.

I would really like to put something across the top of my fencing so that I no longer have to fear this dog entering my yard, as I have two Brittany Spaniels and do not want them to be harmed in any way.

I would appreciate any information you can give me to fix this problem.

Comment: This isn't your problem, if your neighbors cannot keep their dog in their own yard, then they shouldn't have a dog. And please fix your caps lock key.

Comment: You are so right, this is not my problem but it has become my problem because my neighbors are ignorant to the fact...they feel they can have a pet but allow it to do whatever it wants...I do not want my girls hurt by this dog so that is why I am asking for suggestions.

Comment: I would just call Animal Control (or your local equivalent). If it keeps happening, and the owner isn't doing anything to stop it, they should take the dog away and hopefully find it a better home.

Comment: Well, you could shoot the dog, once its on your property...

Comment: Call the cops. They are rarely fans of loose pit bulls.

Comment: Clearly you should keep the dog. It likes you better.

Comment: While shooting the dog is completely within the rights of the property owner, I would suggest a less lethal approach. Bear mace, perhaps? I bet it won't jump the fence again if it associates such an unpleasant feeling with your yard.

Comment: If you can you could consider extend the height of the fence.

Answer (score 13):

[Coyote rollers](http://coyoteroller.com/), won't harm children like barb wire, is effective, and can be home owner installed.

[image]

> A Coyote Roller is a patented ribbed roller that mounts to the top of your fence.  When a coyote or other predator tries to jump your fence to attack your pets, it requires them to grab hold of the top of a fence.  With Coyote Rollers in place, the animals will fall right off of your fence and will not be able to jump over.

Comment: You can make a DIY version of this with PVC pipes suspended on wire run along the top of the fence.  I did this with a wooden fence by installing the wire/pipes between the tops of the wooden fence posts.  Not sure on the best way to secure it with a chain-link fence.

Comment: We had a neighbor with one of these. The coyotes figured that if they couldn't use the top of the fence, they would just jump completely over the fence. Just make sure the fence is high enough.

Answer (score 8):

I'd get some Barbed Wire arms for the fence.

Since a picture is worth 1000 words,

[image]

However, the non technical answer is that it's legally your neighbour's problem.

Depending on your jurisdiction, it might be legal to shoot the dog.

Pitbulls are often great dogs.  But they can also be awful dogs if owned by idiots.

Comment: I like your response :) Although I am against injuring an animal I sure like the idea about the barb-wire..where could I purchase this do you know? And would I be able to do this myself? Thank you again!

Comment: Check out your big box store (Lowes/Home Depot).  They should have these in stock, or at least through order.  I've never done it, but it looks fairly simple to do.  You might need some help tensioning the wire.

Comment: The barbed wire is probably unnecessary - if you can install the angular brackets with something solid (or even just regular wire), it will prevent the dog from being able to get over without being dangerous for kids

Comment: @Steven  good point.

Comment: Dogs can dig too, remember.

Comment: I prefer constantina rolled barb wire!   lol.

Comment: run an electrical cattle wire across the top.  that dog will get a real surprise when he gets to that 40,000 volts!!!!!

Comment: Not that I'm saying this is a BAD pit bull, but pit bulls, in general, have an incredibly high tolerance for pain and if they are aiming to get at something, barbed wire and electric fences will likely pose little-to-no deterrent to the the pit bull. (this is a genetic thing more than anything...hopefully this dog is being raised well and is merely curious in hopping the fence)

Answer (score 2):

You could put an electric fence wire at the top. They make kits that contain a single wire and are powered by a battery and possibly have a solar charger. They do not harm animals and are usually put down near the ground to stop aninals from digging under.

Answer (score 2):

Use chain link fence slats.  It will prevent the dog from climbing the fence and also give you privacy.